# Remover o ID do link quando ele é referenciado com um href

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um projeto de um template, no footer dele tem um botão que leva para o topo do site, ao apertar ele leva para o topo do site mas deixa o id "#top" no link do site (mysite/index.html#top), tem como fazer com que isso não aconteça ?

No body tem um id chamado top:

```
<body id="top">
```

No footer tem um link onde leva para o topo:

```
<a href="#top"> Voltar para o topo </a>
```

Comment: Você poderia editar sua pergunta colocando trecho do código para que a gente possa analisar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com `CSS` creio que não é possível sem a marcação da `url`, mas como marcou a tag `javascript`, é possível fazer isso com poucas linhas da linguagem...

```js
function topFunction(){
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;}
```

```css
.scroll {
  background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px;
}
.example {
  background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 300px
}
.top {
  margin-top: 500px
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">Scroll Down</div>
<div class="example"> 

<button onclick="topFunction()" class="top">Top</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Testei aqui, muito brigado! Aproveitando, pode me indicar algum matérial de javascript para mim ?

Comment: Claro, pode começar com https://pt.slideshare.net/rodrigobranas/java-script-overview, a didática é incrível e tem a série no YouTube também, mas é bom ficar atento a ES6 que está vindo com tudo quando o quesito é front-end, aprendi bastante sobre ES6, webpack, babel, etc... na School of net, então posso recomendar, é pago mas vale a pena  :)